# File.exists() always returns false when using Map Network Drive for a shared folder

Tags: java, file, networking, file-exists

On my Windows Server (2012 R2), I added a shared folder from another server to a Mapped Network Drive (X:) as in the image below.

[image]

Then, I have this snipper code to get files from a specified directory.

```
public void getFiles(String fileLocation) throws Exception {
    File file = new File(fileLocation);
    if (file.exists()) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {                
            //get files from dir
        } else {
            //get file
        }
    } else {
        logger.info("Not found directory: " + fileLocation);
    }
}
```

Now, the weird issue is, on this Windows Server (2012 R2), when I pass `X:\` as the input parameter for the `getFiles()` method, `file.exist()` is then always **false**.

However, If I run the same snipper code with the same input value on other servers (test on another Windows Server 2012 R2, or Windows 10 Pro - my PC), it returns **true** as I expected.

All those machines are joined to the same domain, and of course, they add the same shared resource to the same Map Network Drive (X:)

Does anyone know what could expose this issue?

**UPDATE**

I changed the code to use JAVA 8 API `Files`, but still got the same issue on that Windows 2012 R2 server.

Here is the code running on the server.

```
public void upload(String fileLocation) throws Exception {
    Path filePath = Paths.get(fileLocation);
    if (Files.exists(filePath)) {
        if (Files.isDirectory(filePath)) {
            //get and process multiple files

        } else {
            //process a single file
        }
    } else {
        logger.info("Not found directory '" + fileLocation + "'. Skip uploading files!");
    }
}
```

Debug log of the `upload()` method

[image]

Then, I create a sample console app to test the same logic code on the same server, and it works normally.
The sample console code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileLocation = "Y:\\";

        try {
            File file = new File(fileLocation);
            Files.readAttributes(file.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class);

            if (Files.exists(Paths.get(fileLocation))) {
                System.out.println("Found: " + fileLocation);

                if (Files.isDirectory(Paths.get(fileLocation))) {
                    System.out.println(fileLocation + " is a directory");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(fileLocation + " is a file");
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println("Not Found: " + fileLocation);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while checking file location: " + fileLocation);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I suppose you have already veryfied that the user running the java code can access the file? I.e. have you tested with the same credentials on all machines? All in all, this sounds more like a OS/Networking configuration issue than a programming issue.

Comment: You are calling an old API, for some operations Files gives more details. If you believe the path really should exist try `Files.readAttributes(file.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class)` which might report an exception which shows details of an underlying issue rather than true/false.

Comment: Also check if you are running the exact same version of Java on all the machines on which you run your code.

Comment: The File class should be avoided as much as possible.  Use [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) and [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) instead.  They are more likely to be accurate and they will generate more informative exceptions.

Comment: @Hulk, yes, I think the same thing too, but I need to figure out what exactly the root cause is :|

Comment: @DuncG, please check my UPDATE section above

Comment: @ThomasBehr, yes, I use the same install standalone JDK 1.8 to set up for those machines.

Comment: @VGR, please check my UPDATE section above.

Comment: If the same code works from the command line, but not in a server process, I am inclined to believe user permissions are the culprit.  Do you know if the server process is running as the same user whom you used to open the command window?

Comment: @VGR, they are using the same user login Administrator.